# Y-Axis percentage shows only two values 0% and 100% - Flutter Charts

Tags: flutter

The y-axis is showing two values 0% and 100%. We need the following values 0, 25%, 50%, 75%, and 100%. Tried setting prop `desiredMaxTickCount` but this appears to have no effect. Data series contains a map that has dates for keys and double for values e.g. 04-05-2020:2.0. the keys are displayed in the x-axis and the percentage (double) across the main axis.

We're using the [google_charts](https://github.com/google/charts)

```
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

return new charts.TimeSeriesChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: true,
      layoutConfig: charts.LayoutConfig(
        topMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.fixedPixel(5),
        leftMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.fixedPixel(5),
         bottomMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.fixedPixel(20),
        rightMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.fixedPixel(5)
            
      ),
      defaultRenderer: new charts.LineRendererConfig(
        includeArea: true,
        stacked: true,
      ),
      behaviors: [
        new charts.PercentInjector(
            totalType: charts.PercentInjectorTotalType.domain)
      ],
      primaryMeasureAxis: new charts.PercentAxisSpec(
          renderSpec: new charts.GridlineRendererSpec(
            labelAnchor: charts.TickLabelAnchor.before,
            labelJustification: charts.TickLabelJustification.outside,
          ),
          tickProviderSpec: new charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(
            desiredMaxTickCount: 4,
              zeroBound: false,
          )
      ),

    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `tickProviderSpec` you must set `dataIsInWholeNumbers:false`, or you can specify the values like this:

```
tickProviderSpec: new charts.StaticNumericTickProviderSpec([
              charts.TickSpec(1.0),
              charts.TickSpec(0.75),
              charts.TickSpec(0.5),
              charts.TickSpec(0.25),
              charts.TickSpec(0.0),
            ]
          )
```

Comment: Already solved but Thanks.  Know how to add horizontal & vertical grids to the chart? Default appears to be horizontal only.

Comment: I think that's available only on ```ScatterPlotChart```